# How to get Model List in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this form in MVC Razor . The html is quite long so I am posting the area where I want to work

these are the checkboxes which are populated as service packages

The flow is the user will upload a photo and when proceeds to the next step it goes to a page where he will be selecting service for each photo if he has uploaded 3 photos the three photos will be having the same service

listing but different order IDS

I want is that when a user select services for a specific order means a specific order has multiple services . I want to map it so that Model List will be feteched in the Controller and I can easily insert in the database

this is the HTML:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("PlaceOrder", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id="ServiceForm",@class = "form-horizontal 

white-clr", role = "form" }))
        {
        <!--If user has uploaded a single photo or multiple photo -->

            <div class="window-for-choose-service">
            @if (ViewBag.OrdersList != null)
            {
                int i= 1;


                foreach (var d in ViewBag.OrdersList)
                {
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <img src="@d.ThumbnailPath" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" width="250">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                            <form class="white-clr" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Description</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_@d.ID">
                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                    @foreach (var Services in ViewBag.ServicePackages)
                                    {
                                        int cID = Services.ID + d.ID;
                                        //int rndNumber = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().Next(0, 

11221)).ToString("hmsf"));

                                        if (Services.ServiceParentID == null)
                                        {
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_@d.ID"
                                                       href="#collapseOne_@cID">
                                                        @Services.ServiceName
                                                    </a>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
    <div id="collapseOne_@cID" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    @foreach (var child in Services.ft_service_packages1)
                    {
                        //string ness = "ServiceSelected[" + @d.ID + "]";
                        <div style="width:auto;min-width:250px;float:left; padding:4px; display:inline-block">
                            <div style="float:left;padding-right:5px;">
                                <label for="inlinecheckbox_@child.ID">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ServiceSelect, new { id = "inlinecheckbox_" + 

@child.ID, price_attr = "@child.ServicePrice"})
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UploadOrderID, new { Value = @d.ID })
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding-left:2px;">@child.ServiceName</div>
                        </div>

                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    i++;
                                        }




                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><p class="text-right font-blue"><b> Price $ 

0.0</b></p> </div>
                            </div>

                 }
             }
```

The Html is genereting perfectly fine . But the thing is not getting anything in the controller regarding the model

Model is listed below

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ft_order_itemized
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int UploadOrderID { get; set; }
        public int ServiceSelected { get; set; }
        public decimal ServiceCharges { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ServiceSelectedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OrderID { get; set; }
        public bool ServiceSelect { get; set; }

        public virtual ft_orders ft_orders { get; set; }
        public virtual ft_service_packages ft_service_packages { get; set; }
        public virtual ft_uploads_orders ft_uploads_orders { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller :

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PlaceOrder(ICollection<ft_order_itemized> Orders)
        {
            if (Orders.Count > 0)
            { 

            }

           // ICollection Allstrings = Orders["Service"].ToList();           
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: _The Html is generating perfectly fine_? Hardly. None of your controls are correctly named for posting back to a collection. You need to use `for` loops (not `foreach` which is generating duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes which can't be bound)

Comment: You are right Stephen